# How to plan routes for page with separated sections

Tags: routes, vue-router

All:

I have a single page application in Vue.js, and this page basically is divided into left and right two sections. These two sections currently do not have interaction

I wonder how can I plan the routes(setup router) for this kinda layout, so each section can manage its view?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can have a look at nested routing. [VueRouter Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

Your parent route will be the router-view for your whole wrapper/container. Your child routes will be the one handling the respective sections.

You can wrap `<router-view/>` multiple times in a component depending on your project requirements or criteria

---

An example of the concept above:

**Routes.js**

`/profile` - This will render the container and wrapper

`/profile/resume` - Assuming the resume will be rendered on the right side of the column

**Profile.vue**

```
<div>
  <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column-2>
    // Column 2
    <router-view/> // /profile/resume
  </div>
</div>
```

Then wrap the `Profile.vue` into your main component, mostly `App.vue`

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

---

* Names of components used are suggestive only.

Comment: Thanks, what I am thinking about is more like: the column-1 and column-2 both have router-view in. And each of them just do their own routing. It is like two separated app in same page